# Can not see all assets

Tags: ios, xcode

I import several graphics in my ios projects as you can see as follow:
[image]
The storyboard looks like:
[image]
The button Star...ver I want to assign a StartOverIcon image but it does not list
[image]
Why?

Comment: Try scrolling in the drop down menu, or using the down arrow key... the scroll bar isn't showing which I think you might be mistaking for the other images not being there.

Comment: I find it, thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes different parts of Xcode go out of sync. Just enter the image's name manually and it should work.